# Trying to create a dropdown menu using jQuery but nothing happens

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm learning and trying to create a dropdown menu using jQuery for a nice effect. Clearly I'm doing something wrong 'cause nothing happens. I already checked other similar answers but apparently there's something that I'm missing 'cause I still can't make it work.

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keopimari/8mg32w9u/17/), hope it helps.

```js
$("#menu").hover(function() {
  $(this).find("ul").slideDown("slow");
}, function() {
  $(this).find("ul").slideUp("slow");
});
```

```css
#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu .main-menu {
  display: none;
}

#tm:checked + .main-menu {
  display: block;
}

#menu input[type="checkbox"], 
#menu ul span.drop-icon {
  display: none;
}

#menu li, 
#toggle-menu, 
#menu .sub-menu {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  background-color: rgba(71, 94, 97);
}

#menu li, 
#toggle-menu {
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

#menu .sub-menu {
  background-color: #444;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

#menu .sub-menu li:last-child {
  border-width: 0;
}

#menu li, 
#toggle-menu, 
#menu a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

#menu, 
#toggle-menu {
  background-color: #09c;
}

#toggle-menu, 
#menu a {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu a:hover {
  background-color: #9ba2a3;
  color: #f0f4f5;
}

#menu .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

#menu input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

#menu .sub-menu a:hover {
  color: #444;
}

#toggle-menu .drop-icon, 
#menu li label.drop-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.5em;
  top: 1.25em;
}

#menu label.drop-icon, #toggle-menu span.drop-icon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}

#menu .drop-icon {
  line-height: 1;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 64em) and (min-width: 52.01em) {
  #menu li {
    width: 33.333%;
  }

  #menu .sub-menu li {
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 52em) {
  #menu .main-menu {
    display: block;
  }

  #toggle-menu, 
  #menu label.drop-icon {
    display: none;
  }

  #menu ul span.drop-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  #menu li {
    float: left;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  }

  #menu .sub-menu li {
    float: none;
  }

  #menu .sub-menu {
    border-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 12em;
    z-index: 3000;
  }

  #menu .sub-menu, 
  #menu input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }

  #menu .sub-menu li {
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }

  #menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }

  #menu li:hover > input[type="checkbox"] + .sub-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
   <label for="tm" id="toggle-menu">Menu <span class="drop-icon">▾</span></label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="tm">
   <ul class="main-menu clearfix">
     <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Por habitación
         <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
         <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="PorHabitacion">▾</label>
       </a>
       <input type="checkbox" id="PorHabitacion">
       <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Cocina</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sala</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Comedor</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Balcón</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Baño</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Home-office</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dormitorio
             <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
             <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="Dormitorios">▾</label>
           </a>
           <input type="checkbox" id="Dormitorios">
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Principal</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Nursery</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Infantil</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Juvenil</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>

         <li><a href="#">Exterior
             <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
             <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="Exterior">▾</label>
           </a>
           <input type="checkbox" id="Exterior">
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Jardín</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Balcón</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Terraza</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>

     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Por tipo
           <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
           <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="PorTipo">▾</label>
         </a>
         <input type="checkbox" id="PorTipo">
         <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Departamento</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Casa</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Loft</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Oficina</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Hotel</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Comercio</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>

     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Decoración
           <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
           <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="Decoracion">▾</label>
         </a>
         <input type="checkbox" id="Decoracion">
         <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Iluminación</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Electrodomésticos</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Menaje</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Muebles</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Objetos</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>

     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Ideas y Guías
           <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
           <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="Ideas">▾</label>
         </a>
         <input type="checkbox" id="Ideas">
         <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Proyectos DIY</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Revestimientos</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Pintura</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Mudanza</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Organización</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>

     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Fechas especiales
           <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
           <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="FechasEsp">▾</label>
         </a>
         <input type="checkbox" id="FechasEsp">
         <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Navidad</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Halloween</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Bodas</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Cumpleaños</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">San Valentín</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>

   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your runnable snippet here works?  Your jsfiddle doesn't work because it's not importing jQuery

Comment: Yes your code is working as expected... you just need to do the same collapsing effect with submenus...

Comment: Thanks @Taplar! I just imported the jQuery into the jsfiddle, my bad, sorry.

Comment: @Bilel When I try that the whole transition is gone. I'm probably doing something wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing fine! The fact that it's fully collapsing is due to UL lists selection.
If that's not expected, you could replace it like in the following by limiting the selection to the first UL child.

And the same thing applies on Sub-menus.

```js
$("#menu").hover(function() {
  $(this).children('ul').first().slideDown("slow");
}, function() {
  $(this).children('ul').first().slideUp("slow");
});

$("li:has('label.drop-icon')").hover(function() {
  $(this).children('ul').first().slideDown("slow");
}, function() {
  $(this).children('ul').first().slideUp("slow");
});
```

```css
#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu .main-menu {
  display: none;
}

#tm:checked + .main-menu {
  display: block;
}

#menu input[type="checkbox"], 
#menu ul span.drop-icon {
  display: none;
}

#menu li, 
#toggle-menu, 
#menu .sub-menu {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  background-color: rgba(71, 94, 97);
}

#menu li, 
#toggle-menu {
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

#menu .sub-menu {
  background-color: #444;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

#menu .sub-menu li:last-child {
  border-width: 0;
}

#menu li, 
#toggle-menu, 
#menu a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

#menu, 
#toggle-menu {
  background-color: #09c;
}

#toggle-menu, 
#menu a {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu a:hover {
  background-color: #9ba2a3;
  color: #f0f4f5;
}

#menu .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

#menu input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

#menu .sub-menu a:hover {
  color: #444;
}

#toggle-menu .drop-icon, 
#menu li label.drop-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.5em;
  top: 1.25em;
}

#menu label.drop-icon, #toggle-menu span.drop-icon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}

#menu .drop-icon {
  line-height: 1;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 64em) and (min-width: 52.01em) {
  #menu li {
    width: 33.333%;
  }

  #menu .sub-menu li {
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 52em) {
  #menu .main-menu {
    display: block;
  }

  #toggle-menu, 
  #menu label.drop-icon {
    display: none;
  }

  #menu ul span.drop-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  #menu li {
    float: left;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  }

  #menu .sub-menu li {
    float: none;
  }

  #menu .sub-menu {
    border-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 12em;
    z-index: 3000;
  }

  #menu .sub-menu, 
  #menu input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }

  #menu .sub-menu li {
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }

  #menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }

  #menu li:hover > input[type="checkbox"] + .sub-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
   <label for="tm" id="toggle-menu">Menu <span class="drop-icon">▾</span></label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="tm">
   <ul class="main-menu clearfix">
     <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Por habitación
         <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
         <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="PorHabitacion">▾</label>
       </a>
       <input type="checkbox" id="PorHabitacion">
       <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Cocina</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sala</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Comedor</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Balcón</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Baño</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Home-office</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dormitorio
             <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
             <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="Dormitorios">▾</label>
           </a>
           <input type="checkbox" id="Dormitorios">
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Principal</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Nursery</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Infantil</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Juvenil</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>

         <li><a href="#">Exterior
             <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
             <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="Exterior">▾</label>
           </a>
           <input type="checkbox" id="Exterior">
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Jardín</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Balcón</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Terraza</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>

     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Por tipo
           <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
           <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="PorTipo">▾</label>
         </a>
         <input type="checkbox" id="PorTipo">
         <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Departamento</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Casa</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Loft</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Oficina</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Hotel</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Comercio</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>

     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Decoración
           <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
           <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="Decoracion">▾</label>
         </a>
         <input type="checkbox" id="Decoracion">
         <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Iluminación</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Electrodomésticos</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Menaje</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Muebles</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Objetos</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>

     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Ideas y Guías
           <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
           <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="Ideas">▾</label>
         </a>
         <input type="checkbox" id="Ideas">
         <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Proyectos DIY</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Revestimientos</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Pintura</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Mudanza</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Organización</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>

     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Fechas especiales
           <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
           <label title="toggle drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="FechasEsp">▾</label>
         </a>
         <input type="checkbox" id="FechasEsp">
         <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Navidad</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Halloween</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Bodas</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Cumpleaños</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">San Valentín</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>

   </ul>
 </nav>
```

[EXTRA] : This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bilelh/n2g4cb7t/) use [hoverIntent](https://briancherne.github.io/jquery-hoverIntent/) as an alternative to jQuery hover() method to avoid fast event interaction preventing user from targeting sub-menus.

```
$("body").hoverIntent(function() {
  $(this).children('ul').first().slideDown("slow")},function() {
  $(this).children('ul').first().slideUp("slow");
},'#menu');

$("#menu").hoverIntent(function() {
  $(this).children('ul').first().slideDown("slow")},function() {
  $(this).children('ul').first().slideUp("slow");
},"li:has('label.drop-icon')");
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Bilel ! For some reason this works perfectly in the snippet code that is embedded here (it shows the mobile version of the menu), but in the JSFiddle or on my site with the full version of the menu, the transition in the dropdowns disappears and if I activate any item, the whole thing is gone.

Comment: It's relied to the jQuery version used in your fiddle (I guess you used the last one). So you are right it's a compatibiliy issue! I'll see that tomorrow. But here using version 3.3.1 https://jsfiddle.net/bilelh/3nwx6uah/ everything goes ok

Comment: Suggestion for the mobile view, using a Timeout before the collapse would bring a better navigation experience. especially when you have multiple successive sub-menus. So this way we give the user a short laps to move to the targeted submenu without being disturbed by the collapsing effect.

Comment: You could use Hover Intent plugin to prevent fast hover interaction. https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent

Comment: Thank you so much! for the suggestion too, that's a great idea and like I said, I'm just starting learning so all advice is precious. Thanks :)

Comment: I just updated my answer showing usage of hoverIntent plugin. You are welcome :)

Comment: Don't kill me @Bilel but for some reason I still have the same problem here. There's no transition with an active dropdown and after pointing a menu item the whole thing just disappears :/

Comment: You mean the Fiddle link I added in the extra paragraph? Did you checked your console log errors? How are you loading jQuery.. Is it being loaded before other scripts?

Comment: If I use the hoverintent option it says: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hoverIntent is not a function so of course it doesnt slideup/down.

If I use the other code, the menu is not broken (and the console has no errors) but when I go to an item, it doesn't slide down. And then when I move out of the item, the menu itself slides up and dissappears :P

Comment: hoverIntent is not distributed with jQuery.. It's <script src=> tag  has to be called after jQuery in the document file. You can find it here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.hoverintent or in it's github project.